# Get and set text on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a panel with a few divs with text, i want to get the text of these div and display all in a modal. The content of the div are like Task1,  Planning or URI.

Main structure:

```
 <div id="tasksList" class="row"> //The row of panels
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> /The panel
    <div id="1" class="panel panel-off2">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="row">

      <div class="ptitle">Task 1</div>

      <div class="optiongroup">  <span  data-toggle="modal" id="show" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit yellow"></span>


<div class="miniswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="12">
    <label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></label>
</div> 
  </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">  
        <div class="col-xs-12"><strong>Planning:</strong>&nbsp;0/10 * * * * ?</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" id="uri" value="uri">
          <strong>URI:</strong>&nbsp;/cron/test/task1
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>

... (another div for the second panel)
```

JS of the modal (template is where the content of the modal begin):

```
 $(function() {
    $('#show').avgrund({
      height: 200,
      holderClass: 'custom',
      showClose: true,
      showCloseText: 'close',
      onBlurContainer: '.container',
      template: '    <div class="modal-content">' 
    +
     + '<div class="modal-header">'
      + ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>'
     + '<h4 id="taskDetailTitle" class="modal-title">$("#uri").text()</h4>'
     + '</div>'
   + ' <div class="modal-body">'
    +    '<div class="row-fluid" style="padding-bottom: 0px;">'
+ '<form id="taskForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form">'
 +         '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="2"> '
  +      '  <div class="form-group">'
   +       '  <label for="inputName" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 control-label">Name</label>'

    });
  });
```

Comment: And what is the problem? Apart from the string of html that could/should be a hidden div on the page

Comment: whats the criteria to get the text from div ? any special cond ?

Comment: I want to insert the content of the panel's div to the template part of the modal, but with jquery get and set, because i have a lot of panels and i want to use the same panel template and variable content with jquery.

Comment: No, only get the text of the panel and put in an input text by default in the modal

Comment: could you add a fiddle please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the text of a div with .innerText and you can set the text on a div with .text()

```
<html>
<head>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="load">Hola</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Get text
alert($("#load")[0].innerText);
//Input text
$("#load").text('Write');
//Get the input
alert($("#load")[0].innerText);
</script>
</html>
```